# Accepted one job offer, next day got a better offer!

Tags: job-offer

Got a job offer yesterday & accepted, making 9.oo hr, 2 hrs a day Monday through Friday, today got another offer making 12.00 an hr. 30 hrs, a week, I feel extremely bad, what should I say to them when I call!

Comment: "I'm sorry I feel really bad about this but I've got another opportunity and I have to retract my acceptance"

Comment: Unless you are bound by some kind of contact (which I doubt), you should be able to quit at any time including before you start. Telling the $9/hr job that you are retracting your job acceptance is better than never showing up for the job!

Comment: Happened to me; I just called and said due to circumstances I won't be able to take up the job any more. Better to let them know sooner than later -- most likely they had other applicants & you have just given someone else an unexpected opportunity when they offer it to the next guy!

Answer (score 8):

Different industries have different expectations of their employees.

Generally, the lower the wage, the higher the turnover but also the lower the investment they make in recruiting. I'm not saying this is an excuse to blow off a job offer, but I am saying it will soften the blow.

A firm that is paying an employee for only two hours of work a day at barely above minimum wage is likely prepared for a high turnover rate. You probably feel worse about this than they do. Let them know immediately the simple fact that you will be unable to work the position so they can begin the hunt for their next employee.

Simply put, you can't pass up an offer that gives you 4x the money. I'm not sure anyone can.

Unless the times don't conflict, in which case consider working them both.